# Python Outlook getting all emails from Sender

Tags: python

I am trying to use python to go through outlook and get all emails by a sender. I have looked but can't find out how to do this. I can get an email by subject and return the sender, but I am looking to get all senders and then return the subject? This is what I am using to get sender by subject.

```
import win32com.client


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages("Test 08/18/14")
print(message.sender)
```

This returns the sender for the mail with the subject "Test 08/19/14"

I would like to go through my email and get all email subjects from a certain sender.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the [SenderEmailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171942%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property.

You could go through your messages for a particular sender via:

```
for m in messages:
   if m.SenderEmailAddress == 'some_sender@somewhere.com':
       print(m)
```

Comment: This works but if you have a PDL or group address it will fail.